# Check if element contains child with data id

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
const addToList = function ({ name, id }) {
  let html1 = `
  <li class="list-item" data-id="${id}" id="${id}">
  ${name}
  <span>&nbsp</span>
  <button class="btn-remove">remove</button>
  </li>
  `;
  pokemonList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html1);
};

const displayListItem = function () {
  favourite.forEach((listItem) => {
    addToList(listItem);
  });
};

let favourite = getStorageItem('pokemon');
pokemonContainer.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('btn-favourites')) {
    favourite = getStorageItem('pokemon');
    let eTargetID = parseInt(e.target.dataset.id);
    let found = favourite.some((el) => el.id === eTargetID);
    console.log(found);
    console.log(eTargetID);
    if (!found) {
      favourite.push(pokemonArray[e.target.dataset.id - 1]);
      setStorageItem('pokemon', favourite);
      // behöver lösa duplcates i favorit listan
      displayListItem(favourite);
    }
  }
});
```

How do I check if a child element with a dataset id exists? I want to prevent duplicate from appearing in my favourite list when I get them from local storage when I click on a button, if a li tag already exists with a specific dataset id.

Right now when I click let's say bulbasaur, I get bulbasaur in my list. If i then click ivysaur, I get bulbasaur, bulbasaur, ivysaur.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use querySelector, that dynamically accepts an id to search, for example:

```
document.querySelector(`[data-id="${datasetId}"]`)
```

Returns the element if exists, if not returns null.

Comment: oooo Didnt know you could use querySelector like that. Thanks!